# PostgreSQL WITH query

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

This is what is written in the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-with.html):

```
WITH t AS (
    UPDATE products SET price = price * 1.05
    RETURNING *
)
SELECT * FROM products;
```

the outer SELECT would return the original prices before the action of the UPDATE, while in

```
WITH t AS (
    UPDATE products SET price = price * 1.05
    RETURNING *
)
SELECT * FROM t;
```

the outer SELECT would return the updated data.

---

My question is.... What if I want to have a column that shows the diffrance between the before and after update data?
for example if it was `5` then changed to `6`. I want to see `1`.
in order to do that I need price column before and after.
Something like:

```
WITH t AS (
    UPDATE products SET price = price * 1.05
    RETURNING *
)
SELECT *,new.price-old.price FROM ?;
```

None of the examples above shows how to do it.
I know this can be solved with other ways but I want to know if it's possible to do it with `WITH` statment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join them together:

```
WITH t AS (
    UPDATE products SET price = price * 1.05
    RETURNING *
)
SELECT p.*, t.price, (t.price - old.price) as diff
FROM products p JOIN
     t
     ON p.productid = t.productid;
```